# How to Implement A* on Titan Graph Database?

Tags: graph-databases, dijkstra, a-star, titan, tinkerpop3

I am using Titan 1.0.0 and Cassandra as a backend.

I have location data (latitude, longitude) as a nodes and edges between these nodes. I want to find shortest path from node A to node B. The graph size is very large. Currently I am using this query to find path between two nodes.

```
g.V(fromNode).repeat(both().simplePath()).until(is(toNode)).limit(1).path().fill(list);
```

This query is very inefficient and gives memory error for path size more than 10. 
After reading about shortest path algorithms, I got to know that implementing A* will be more feasible than implementing Dijkstra's as in A* less graph will be explored.

Now I can use JUNG and load TitanGraph into the memory and implement my own A* to get shortest path. But I don't want whole graph to be inside memory.

Kindly suggest me on how should I implement A* on TitanGraph. Should I query graph using API or should I load graph into memory first then run the A* on in-memory graph.

I will be thankful for any other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a question more associated with Tinkerpop3 rather than Titan. I agree with you that loading the graph in memory is a totally bad idea.

The best way is to implement the A star algorithm to run straight on the Gremlin console.

The Gremlin console executes [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code. You could implement the A* algorithm on a `.groovy` file and load it to Gremlin console this way:

```
gremlin> :load my_folder/a-star-algo-tp3.groovy
```

Let's say you defined a method inside this file called:

```
List<Element> a_star_algo(Graph graph, Object fromId, Object toId)
```

You could just call it from your gremlin console this way:

```
list = a_star_algo(graph, v1.id(), v2.id())
```

You may implement this method using A* algorithm. This [repo](https://github.com/dgt79/little_dragon/blob/master/src/dgt/graph/Graph.groovy#L74) implements the algorithm using their own data structure in Groovy. I'm not sure how efficient their implementation is but you may have a look.

Comment: Thanks :). Currently I have implemented using Java. And it is not taking much time to execute. I will try this approach too. Thank You.